# ReactJS - Maintaining common model between Parent and Child

Tags: reactjs, model-view-controller, model, state

My component view looks as below. DataList has multiple DataItems and each DataItem has a Header and Body and Header in-turn has Expandable section with a button which will toggle the visibility of corresponding DataItem's Body.

And DataItem, Header, Expandable, Body are independent components and whenever expandable button is clicked I've to pass/lift the 'expandable' state all the way up to Header & DataItem to add a css class to DataItem to show/hide the Body section.

So along with Expandable, even Header and DataItem should also hold 'expandable' states which is redundant and creates tight coupling between the components.

Is there a way to hold common state(aka Model in MVC) which can be re-used across the components in ReactJS ?

```
DataList
|
|-DataItem-1
|    |
|    |-Header
|    |   |
|    |   |-Expandable
|    |
|    |-Body
|     
|-DataItem-2
|    |
     |-Header
     |   |
     |   |-Expandable
     |
     |-Body
```

Comment: Use Redux or similar state-maintaining solution?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need to add a css class to DataItem to show/hide the Body section. You can achieve that with [React's Conditional Rendering](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html).

#### How to avoid redundant states?

**DataItem.js**

```
import Expandable from './Header';
import Body from './Body';

class DataItem extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { showBody: false };
    }

    onExpandableClick = () => {
        this.setState({ showBody: !this.state.showBody });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header onExpandableClick={this.onExpandableClick} {...otherHeaderProps} />
                { this.state.showBody && <Body {...bodyProps} />}
                {/* other elements */}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**Header.js**

```
import Expandable from './Expandable';

class Header extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Expandable onClick={this.props.onExpandableClick} />
                {/* other elements */}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**Expandable.js**

```
class Expandable extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div onClick={this.props.onClick}>
                {/* other elements */}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

---

#### Common state (global store), the Model in MVC

We have many solutions (state management libraries) for handling the global state of our app.

- [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/) (the great old man)
- [Reflux](https://github.com/reflux/refluxjs) (i don't know him personally)
- [Redux](http://redux.js.org/) (my favorite)
- [MobX](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx) (new and powerful)
- ...

Talking about my favorite, Redux, it maintains the state of an entire application in a single immutable state tree (object), which can’t be changed directly. When something changes, a new object is created (using actions and reducers).

Redux got popular very quickly because of its simplicity, small size (only 2 KB) and great documentation. As the author of Redux says,

> "Redux API surface is tiny. If you remove the developer warnings,
> comments, and sanity checks, **it's 99 lines**. There is no tricky async
> code to debug."

Find the comprehensive documentation [**here**](http://redux.js.org/).

Comment: I see the same tight-coupling in your code as well, because Expandable is an atomic / independent utility and can be used with any other component, not just DataItem.

In above code `DataItem` shouldn't directly deal with expandable state as it is owned by the Expandable utility. Ideally there should a `Model` instance that should be common state which should be accessible to both DataItem and Expandable and both should listen to the Model instance. Expandable should update the 'expandable' state of the Model so that DataItem will re-render itself which will toggle the Body section.

Answer (score 0):

Never duplicate the same state item over multiple component states. This will lead to issues down the line, as they always need to be kept synchronized manually.

In this situation, I would **define the expanded property as a property of the `DataItem` itself, not of the body**. This allows you to keep the info in the state of the `DataItem` and pass it down where required. Do not keep the info in the header, but pass a callback into the `Header` component that allows it to toggle the property.

This could be implemented similar to the snippet below. Run the snippet to see it in action!

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    
    this.toggleExpand = this.toggleExpand.bind(this)
    
    this.state = {
      expanded: true
    }
  }
  
  toggleExpand() {
    this.setState({
      expanded: !this.state.expanded
    })
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header toggleExpand={this.toggleExpand} />
        <Body expanded={this.state.expanded} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const Header = props => (
  <div id='header'>
    <button onClick={props.toggleExpand}>
      Toggle Expand
    </button>
  </div>
)

const Body = props => (
  props.expanded ?
    <div id='body'>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>
  : null
)

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

```css
#header, #body {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'></div>
```